# How to make spring boot code generic or dynamic if my requirement is both postgresql and sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc

1. For example

   ```
   sqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + table_name + " WHERE " + timeKey + " like '%"
                   + currentDate + "%' AND game_type = '" + game_type + "'";
   ```

   I used query like above in my spring boot code, this query means
   that

   ```
   Select COUNT(*) from table_one where timestamp like "2020-03-07%" And game_type ='Darksider';
   ```
2. This query works fine with mssql or sql server but it gives error when I use postgresql in my spring boot code .
3. I dont want to change my query and make two different projects for mssql and postgresql I want my code to be dynamic so how can I implement it so that my spring code works fine with both postgresql and mssql .

Comment: Does anyone know???

Comment: Should I apply databse migration or what ?

Comment: What error do you get when using above query with psql?

Comment: Actually sir the thing is this query is supported in mssql but is does not support postgresql because in postgre I need to type cast the timestamp

Comment: But what I want is to make my queries in that way that it will support both postgre and sqlserver

Comment: I want my project to be generic so that it will be compatible with any database

Comment: Your project wont be compatible with any database, that's not really possible. But, you can write the same query for most of relational databases by using `Java Persistence Query Language (JPQL)` or `Hibernate Query Language (HQL)`. Please look into them.

Comment: @Ervin Szilagyi So sir can I use criteria query??

Comment: But the thing is my project is working when I use mssql as my database but its not working in postgresql so If I use any of Hql or JPQL than I have to change my whole project

Comment: You need to for JPA criteria query.